# .off not working with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a small test code because I was unsure about whether listeners could be turned off outside of the scope in which they were called and I am wondering why in my test code, when I include a callback in the .off method, the code no longer seems to work.

```
var testobj = {
    init: function() {
        testobj.listener();
    },

    listener: function() {

        $(document).on('mousedown', function() {
            testobj.listener_off();
                console.log("on");
        });


    },

    listener_off: function() {
        $(document).on('mouseup', function() {
            $(document).off('mousedown', function() {
                console.log("off");
            });
        });
    }
}

$(function() {
    testobj.init();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xxkL/)

So once again, the issue is that:

```
$(document).off('mousedown', function() {
    console.log("off");
});
```

seems to break the code, while using:

```
$(document).off('mousedown');
```

appears to work just fine.

Additionally, when dealing with multiple event listeners (especially those which react to the same event), what is considered best practice for calling them on and off? Am I right in separating them into separate functions so they may be called later or might that cause problems?

Comment: The second argument to `.off()` is the handler that you want to remove. Since that anonymous function doesn't match an existing handler, it doesn't remove anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a function in to `.off()`, it means that you want to remove that particular handler. Since you're passing a newly-instantiated anonymous function, it's *not* a handler for any event, so there's no net effect.

That form of `.off()` makes sense when you've got a handler function to which you've got a reference: a variable name, or a property name of some object, etc. That way you can use the function by that reference in setting up an event handler, and then again when you want to un-set it:

```
function someHandler(ev) {
  // handle handle handle ...
}

// ...

$('#foo').on('click', someHandler);

// ...

if (itsChristmasTime()) {
  $('#foo').off('click', someHandler);
}
```

In your case, you probably just need the one-argument version, passing just the event name. Another way to keep track of event handlers is to use a qualifier on the event name. JQuery looks for a "." in the event name, and ignores the "." and any suffix for the purposes of event handling, but it doesn't completely forget. Thus you can use that to identify a handler without needing to keep track of the particular function in use:

```
$('#foo').on('click.remove-me', function(ev) { ... });

// ...

if (itsChristmasTime()) {
  $('#foo').off('click.remove-me');
}
```

That way you can maintain separate "click" handlers for different aspects of your widget's behavior, and selectively remove only one/some of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when passing a function as the second argument to the [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function it should be the **same function instance that was registered**.

Bascially, the following will **not** be working:

```
$(myDiv).on('click', function () {});
$(myDiv).off('click', function () {});
```

But this would:

```
function clickHandler() {}

$(myDiv).on('click', clickHandler);
$(myDiv).off('click', clickHandler);
```

When you call [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) without a second parameter it removes all listeners for that specific event, that's why it's working in your case.